# Python 2.5 Tkinter Highlight Spinbox Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, spinner, tkinter-entry

This question seems trivial to me but I can't seem to find anything related to it, and the Spinbox docs don't seem to help.

Is there any way to select all of the text in a Spinbox widget?

I'm currently trying:

```
self.spinbox.selection_clear()
self.spinbox.selection('range', 0, END)
```

to no avail.

I have this bound to a mouse-click on the spinbox. The first time you click on it, all the entry text will be highlighted, and subsequent times it will not, unless a boolean variable has been reset. I've had no problem doing this with entry widgets, but this spinbox seems to give me trouble. Am I using the function wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experimentation, I think the Spinbox needs to explicitly have focus in order for `selection` to do anything. Try:

```
self.spinbox.selection_clear()
self.spinbox.focus_set()
self.spinbox.selection('range', 0, END)
```

Comment: I feel I will need to scrap this idea from my program, this solution doesn't seem to work for me. My entry widgets may be interfering with this somehow (at one location I `return "break"` to allow a selection to be highlighted). With this change implemented, sometimes the spinbox text will all be highlighted upon clicking an arrow button, but never from a regular click on the spinbox entry field.

Comment: Interesting... I think I would need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to investigate further, though

Comment: Odd, I've just tried to build an example that would react how my code does and it works perfectly fine using your solution...I will update if I figure anything out. I can't post my actual code as there is some sensitive material & it interacts with PSSE so  it wouldn't work either way.